# Is there a regular expression that matches a string of ANY different letters (in bash/sed/python)?

Tags: regex

Inspired by today's Advent of Code task I was wondering whether it is possible to use regex to find in a string a substring of a given length that consists of different letters. For example:

Given length 4, the only substring that consists of different letters from:
`asbshbsbuhb` is `sbuh`. Every other 4 letter substring has duplicate letters.

Is there any way (not over-complicated one) to use regex to find such substrings given either bash or sed or python?

Comment: Plain trad regex, no. Please review the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for ways to clarify the question if you mean a specific extended regex variant.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, I added some languages that I use

Comment: This all assumes the length of the series of unique characters is known. Making that variable greatly complicates the problem. Is the length fixed and known?

Comment: Well, no, it should be a variable.

Comment: Then it is probably impossible, though your question did explicitly say "of a given length". In the very least it has to have a maximum length to check, and probably a minimum. What are those? Otherwise even if you manage to find a good regex it will probably run till the heat death of the universe on any very complicated pattern...  (I recommend Jeff Friedl's [book on it](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/).)

Answer (score 2):

Saying "in `bash`" I usually try to do something in the interpreter, but most modern `grep`s have a "Perl" mode, so you could (using tripleee's lookahead syntax, as Jay pointed out) do this -

```
$: grep -oP '(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3).' <<< asbshbsbuhb
sbuh
```

...which is *kind of* doing it in `bash`, for some values of "in bash"?

Obviously `python` can do it already.
`sed` is trickier... It isn't exactly "one regex", but this `sed` script will return the first four-unique-character sequence from the example string you provided.

```
sed -nE ':l;s/^.?.?(.)\1/\1/;tl;s/^.?(.)(.)\1/\2\1/;tl;s/^(.)(.)(.)\1/\2\3\1/;tl;s/(....).*/\1/;p;' <<< asbshbsbuhb
sbuh
```

It uses `sed` anchor and conditional branch logic, testing for various disqualifying combinations and removing the characters from the input string up through the first that gets repeated within the four-character set, walking through the string until it hits a set with no dups, which it prints.

Answer (score 1):

With negative lookaheads, you can, though it's arguably rather tortured.

```
(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3).
```

Bash and `sed` lack this facility, but Python supports it.

Demo: https://ideone.com/MlAYC5

(The demo uses different numbering so that the entire match is group 1, to support the conventions of Python's `re.findall`.)

Comment: `grep -P -o` should be able to parse that expression as well, right?

Comment: Clearly yes, if you have a `grep` which supports `-P`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial **regex** solution, that just looks for **4 letter words**, and then uses some **python** code to identify if any of them have a **unique** sequence of characters.

#### Code:

```
import re

text = 'asbshbsbuhb'

m = re.findall(r'(?=([A-Za-z]{4}))', text)

for word in m:
    if len(set(word)) == len(word):
        print(word)
```

#### Output:

```
sbuh
```

Comment: that was my solution as well, but I would like to limit the solution to regex only